# Disable Button from another view controller with a switch with swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Ok so I am trying to make it when the user flips the cheat mode switch it will disable the answerButton. I did try to set the button to disable near the bottom however it does not appear to do anything. I added the print("") to see if it would print in the console however nothing was printed. I a unsure what is wrong here.

I have pasted my code below.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class SettingsController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var cheatSwitch: UISwitch!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    cheatSwitch.isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func saveSettings(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(cheatSwitch.isOn, forKey: "switchState")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let mainView : ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController

    if cheatSwitch.isOn == true {
        print("turn off button")
        mainView.btnAnswer.isEnabled = false;

    }

    else {
        print("turn on button")
        mainView.btnAnswer.isEnabled = true;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Have you double checked the links in the storyboard?

Comment: Yea the buttons and links work. It just wont disable the button on the main view.

Comment: Is it not printing one of the print statement in console ? Also there is no code of  `performSegue` show how you are moving to the `ViewController`?

Comment: Nope it's not printing the prints in the console

Comment: @winter4w How you are moving to `ViewController`? There is no code of `performSegue`.

Comment: @ Nirav D I am useing a Navigation Controller

Comment: @winter4w What do you mean by `Navigation Controller`?, are you talking about back button?

Comment: @NiravD Yea I am using the back button.

Comment: @winter4w That back button never call `prepareforsegue` method.

Comment: @winter4w Check my solution and add `viewDidAppear` method in your `ViewController` class.

Comment: @NiravD Ok I added a normal button now and still am haveing the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving the value `UISwitch`'s state in `UserDefaults` so you can use its value in `ViewController's` method `viewDidApper`.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.btnAnswer.isEnabled = !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
}
```

**Note:** There is no need to add `prepareForSegue` in your `SettingsController` because it will never called when you press back button of `NavigationController` so consider to remove it.

Comment: @winter4w Check the edited answer it is typo mistake. Use self instead of mainView and don't make any changes with navigationController.

Comment: Now I get Value of type 'SettingsController' has no member 'btnAnswer'

Comment: @winter4w Check my answer properly I have told you to add this method inside your `ViewController` not inside the `SettingsController`.

Comment: @winter4w Welcome mate :)